# Local edits to recipes get overwritten by chef-client execution

Tags: chef-infra, chef-client

I am a dev tasked with making some changes to the cookbooks owned by the devops team. We don't have access to knife or the chef server.

I tried to make some local changes to a recipe to try it out. But, when I run:

```
$ sudo chef-client --log_level debug
```

the local changes to the recipe are overriden by what's on the server.

Is there a way to quickly test minor changes to recipes without fetching them from the chef server?

Thank you.

Comment: Helpful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47932215/unable-to-find-cookbooks-in-local-mode-with-chef-client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `--skip-cookbook-sync` parameter to your command:

```sh
$ sudo chef-client --log_level debug --skip-cookbook-sync
```